# Does Google App Engine provide any ways to test the application performance against high amount of traffic?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I have deployed an application to `Google App Engine` which will be consumed by millions of users.

I want to test the application against high amount of traffic before go live just to make sure i have provided the correct configuration that supports auto load balancing and scale-ability.

While going through google documentations. `App Engine` should handle all of this headache, but i have to be sure 100%.

Is there are anything should i put in mind before go live (database connection, other resources in the cloud storage,..., etc.)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should look into making sure your are using the Cloud SQL instance effectively. For example, how many total connections do you expect to have from your app engine to MySQL?

There's ultimately a limit on the number of concurrent connections that a MySQL server can handle. You would want to make sure your application is designed such that you are reusing connections when possible.

I would recommend performing a load test to determine the limits of your application and its dependencies.

Comment: sounds like you try to test number of sessions that the database would handle meanwhile i'm interested to know if GAE will help me in getting out of such a bottle nick ? if not why i should use it !

Comment: If you use Datastore instead of Cloud SQL, you would have less things to worry about as Datastore will scale with your application with less work required from you. If you choose to use a MySQL server, you need to be aware of its scaling behavior, App Engine can't handle it for you.

Comment: you can add a read replica to Cloud SQL with a few clicks then offload read and write contention. If you are using connection pooling properly this architecture should handle serious load.. p.s. make sure you use a 2nd gen machine and size up the SSD a bit to start.